# Azure container registry repository or image delete giving error while executing using Azure CLI or Command Shell

Tags: azure, repository, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, azure-cloud-shell

Getting below error while deleting ACR repository or image.

Command: $ az acr repository delete --name pocacr2021 -repository repoNodeBulletin

Error: The requested data does not exist.  Correlation Id:xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Error was coming due to passing repository name should be lower case. It won't allow upper or mixed case.

Wrong Command: $ az acr repository delete --name pocacr2021 -repository **repoNodeBulletin**

Correct Command: $ az acr repository delete --name pocacr2021 -repository **reponodebulletin**